# How to plot timeline graph using Matplotlib in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a csv that consists data of user activity on a particular social media app, the csv contains records of the last 30 days I want to retrieve data of just the first day which I did and stored in a dataframe

The dataframe looks something like

```
            From                          To               Status
0   2020-08-01 05:16:00     2020-08-01 05:19:05               N
1   2020-08-01 05:19:05     2020-08-01 05:22:10               Y
2   2020-08-01 05:22:10     2020-08-01 05:23:12               N
3   2020-08-01 06:23:12     2020-08-01 06:42:46               Y
4   2020-08-01 06:42:46     2020-08-01 06:45:51               N
```

The dataframe contains 100 rows

Y stands for Yes, the user was active.
N stands for No, the user was not active.

I want the output to look something like this
[image]

I saw a similar question like this but it couldn't help me in anyway

Answer (score 2):

For drawing Gantt chart-like graphs, there are [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/gantt/) and [altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/bar_chart_horizontal.html). I used the easiest one, 'altair', to draw this. You can draw the graph as it is in the data structure.

```
import altair as alt

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x = 'From',
    x2 = 'To',
    y = alt.Y('Status')
)
chart
```

[image]